# Get class object from class type

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a class type String which return from WebService called `MainViewController` and I want to get a class object from it. It always fails.

This is my code:

```
    let classStringFromWS = "MainViewController"
    if let viewControllerString = NSClassFromString(classStringFromWS) as? UIViewController.Type {
        let viewController = viewControllerString.init(nibName: classStringFromWS, bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: what for ???????

Comment: The class string itself returns from web service

Comment: you cant dynamically generate it and get it compiled it can works with storyboard that you set the identifier dynamically not with nib

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

Use factory function (anyway to create instance of class, the class must be available, so) assuming it is available in same module

```
func createInstance(for className: String) -> UIViewController? {
    // registry of supported controllers
    let classRegistry: [String: UIViewController.Type] = [
        "MainViewController": MainViewController.self
        // other supported controllers here
    ]

    if let aClass = classRegistry[className] {
        return aClass.init(nibName: className, bundle: nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @YossiTsafar, even if you get class name from WS, the class itself must be present in run-time. So where it is? Where did you declare it (ie. `class MainViewController: UIViewController {...}`?